# divisibility of numbers cast to varchar type

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, sqldatatypes

I have cast a number to varchar as below,

```
SELECT (266::VARCHAR)/2
```

This query is returning result as `133.000000..`

[image: result screenshot]

I was expecting an error. But got above result. Why?

Comment: Because of auto casting. The divide by 2 make the sql compiler try cast the string to a number. And it coverts.

Answer (score 0):

In my Snowflake account, I am not getting the decimal places via the webui

But auto-casting to trying "make things just work" is the reason.

```
SELECT 266 as an_int
    ,an_int::text as as_text
    ,SYSTEM$TYPEOF(an_int) as type_an_int
    ,SYSTEM$TYPEOF(as_text) as type_an_int
    ,an_int/2 as int_div_2
    ,as_text/2 as text_div_2
    ,(266::VARCHAR)/2 as magic;
```

| AN_INT | AS_TEXT | TYPE_AN_INT | TYPE_AN_INT_2 | INT_DIV_2 | TEXT_DIV_2 | MAGIC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 266 | 266 | NUMBER(3,0)[SB2] | VARCHAR(16777216)[LOB] | 133 | 133 | 133 |

But via SnowSQL:

```
>SELECT 266 as an_int
    ,an_int::text as as_text
    ,SYSTEM$TYPEOF(an_int) as type_an_int
    ,SYSTEM$TYPEOF(as_text) as type_an_int
    ,an_int/2 as int_div_2
    ,as_text/2 as text_div_2
    ,(266::VARCHAR)/2 as magic;
+--------+---------+------------------+------------------------+------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| AN_INT | AS_TEXT | TYPE_AN_INT      | TYPE_AN_INT            |  INT_DIV_2 |      TEXT_DIV_2 |           MAGIC |
|--------+---------+------------------+------------------------+------------+-----------------+-----------------|
|    266 | 266     | NUMBER(3,0)[SB2] | VARCHAR(16777216)[LOB] | 133.000000 | 133.00000000000 | 133.00000000000 |
+--------+---------+------------------+------------------------+------------+-----------------+-----------------+
1 Row(s) produced. Time Elapsed: 0.281s
```

Comment: You will see decimals in the classic web console as well. In Snowsight, you'd have to click on the cell and look at the stats pane on the right hand side next to the results to see the decimals.

Answer (score 0):

> *I was expecting an error. But got above result. Why?*

When data types varies the mechanism called **implicit casting**/**type coercion** takes places.

[Implicit Casting (“Coercion”)](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-type-conversion.html#implicit-casting-coercion):

> Coercion occurs when a function (or operator) requires a data type that is different from, but compatible with, the arguments (or operands).
>
> ....
>
> **Data Types that Can Be Cast**
>
> The table below shows the valid data type conversions in Snowflake. The table also shows which **coercions Snowflake can perform automatically.**
>
> [image]